# Swift Generics 'Event<U>' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I am trying to make Event and Interval generic, but running into this error with the init method.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
protocol Interval {
        associatedtype T: Comparable
        var start: T { get }
        var end: T { get }
        var max: T { get set } }

    public class Event <U: Comparable> : Interval {
        typealias T = U

        private (set) var start: T
        private (set) var end: T
        var max: T

        var left: Event<T>?
        var right: Event<T>?

        init(start: T, end: T) {

            precondition(start <= end)

            self.start = start
            self.end = end
            self.max = end
        }
    }

var tree = IntervalTree<Int>()
tree.insert(Event<Int>(start: 5, end: 10)) <- 'Event<U>' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level
```

Answer (score 3):

The default access level is `internal`, which means it's only available within the current module. I suspect you're accessing this code from another module.

Your init uses the default access level:

```
init(start: T, end: T) {
```

To resolve this, make it public:

```
public init(start: T, end: T) {
```

Comment: That's my first thought, but making it public resole in the following error: Initializer cannot be declared public because its parameter uses an internal type.  You are welcome to try it on the playground.

Comment: Right; the typealias T is also internal. (But it's not clear why it exists. I would get rid of T, or get rid of U.) You'll likely find that your properties like `max` and `start` should also be public. Anything you want to access outside the module needs to be marked public.